# How to get containter memory limit in Python?

Tags: python, docker, memory, get, limit

I'm trying to retrieve the real memory limit set to a Docker container within it using Python:

`docker run --rm -it --memory="2g" python:3.8 python -c "import os; print((os.sysconf('SC_PAGE_SIZE') * os.sysconf('SC_PHYS_PAGES'))/(1024.**3))"`

but it returns all available memory from the host machine.

I know I could use Docker package for Python and bind-mount `/var/run/docker.sock` to get that info from inspecting container configuration, but I need to know if there is another way because I can't use that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Container's memory limit is controlled by linux cgroups, so you could fetch the value of `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes` in container to caculate the limit memory within container:

```
root@pie:~# docker run --rm -it --memory="2g" python:3.8 /bin/bash
root@e22c4275f26c:/# python3
Python 3.8.15 (default, Oct 14 2022, 00:19:58)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> limit_in_bytes=subprocess.check_output(["cat", "/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes"]).decode("utf-8")
>>> print(int(limit_in_bytes)/(1024**3))
2.0
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

For cgroups2:

```
vasya@fbi:~$ docker run -it --rm -u1000:1000 -m 128m --memory-reservation 64m python:3.11
Python 3.11.8 (main, Mar 12 2024, 11:41:52) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path("/sys/fs/cgroup/memory.low").read_text()
'67108864\n'
>>> Path("/sys/fs/cgroup/memory.max").read_text()
'134217728\n'
>>>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).